# i get TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function all the time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am new all around  jquery and ajax in ASP.net MVC. i would like that one of my text fields will be autocompleted. for now this is my implementation but for some reason i got this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

and when i go inside i get:

```
 <anonymous>
 Create:36
jQuery.Callbacks/fire()
 jquery-1.10.2.js:3048
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith()
 jquery-1.10.2.js:3160
.ready()
 jquery-1.10.2.js:433
completed()
 jquery-1.10.2.js:104
```

this is my view file create.cshtml:

```
   @model StudentsManagment.Models.student
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#citySearch").autocomplete({
            source: function(request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/AutoCompleteCountry",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Country, value: item.Country };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First_name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Last_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last_name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Student_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Student_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("searchCity", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "citySearch" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

does it a jquery error or something with my cshtml file is wrong?

Comment: you have use query-ui-1.10.4.custom.min, so dose your custom jqui file have autocomplete methode? and your are facing typeErro so might you are passing wrong data type value

Comment: what do you mean "custom jqui file" should i build one like this? i do not pass nothing when the page is loading i click F12 and i see this kind of error

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for that?

Comment: i prefer not i am just looked for an example how to use the autocomplete method with jquery in asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please check that your Layout file doesn't have a jquery or jquery UI. If it does then due to duplicate files it may be causing issue.

Also I suggest you move all your script files and javascript code at the bottom of the page instead of top of the page.

Comment: i does not have other files in the layout as you can read but i have other js files in the script folder does its matter?

Comment: no it doesn't matter. can you check that jquery UI file is loading correctly. Also you haven't posted Layout file here so I cannot see.

Comment: the layout file is the cshtm file!

Comment: i found that the error in this line :  $("#citySearch").autocomplete